# Why is my Python code ignoring my if-statement and not quitting when I add the answer "no"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
print("Welcome to my quiz page!")
playing = input("Do you want to play? ")
if playing.lower() == "yes":   #when people answer no here, the quiz should stop but it doesn't. why?   
    print("Let's play! ")
    score = 0

answer = input("What is the capital of Japan? ")
if answer.lower() == "tokyo":
    print("Correct!")
    score += 1
else:
    print("Incorrect!")

answer = input("What is a female Japansese dress called? ")
if answer.lower() == "kimono":
    print("Correct!")
    score += 1
else:
    print("Incorrect!")

answer = input("What are Japanese gang members called? ")
if answer.lower() == "yakuza":
    print("Correct!")
    score += 1
else:
    print("Incorrect!")

print("You've got " + str(score) + " questions correct!")
print("You've got " + str((score / 3) * 100) + "%,")
```

When I answer `"no"` it still let me carry on playing the quiz instead of quitting. How can I stop it running when people answer no instead of yes?

Comment: you don't have a condition for `no` or `yes`

Comment: Your indentation is clearly wrong; please [edit] to fix it. On the desktop version of this site, you can get code marked up for you by pasting your code, selecting the pasted block, and typing ctrl-K.

Comment: Why *would* it stop? All that `if` controls is the "Let's play!" message and the score initialization.

Comment: You will need to test user input for 'yes' and 'no'. You're not doing that. Also, you should consider making this "table driven" otherwise you're going to have at least 6 lines of code for every possible question and answer and no way to break out early

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quiz does not stop because you have not included any code to stop the quiz when the user enters "no". To fix this, you can add an else statement after the if statement that checks if the user wants to play. The else statement should contain a break statement to exit the loop.

Here How you can do so:

```
print("Welcome to my quiz page!")

while True:
    playing = input("Do you want to play? ")
    if playing.lower() == "yes" or playing.lower() == "y":
        print("Let's play! ")
        score = 0

        answer = input("What is the capital of Japan? ")
        if answer.lower() == "tokyo":
            print("Correct!")
            score += 1
        else:
            print("Incorrect!")

        answer = input("What is a female Japansese dress called? ")
        if answer.lower() == "kimono":
            print("Correct!")
            score += 1
        else:
            print("Incorrect!")

        answer = input("What are Japanese gang members called? ")
        if answer.lower() == "yakuza":
            print("Correct!")
            score += 1
        else:
            print("Incorrect!")
        
        print("You've got " + str(score) + " questions correct!") 
        print("You've got " + str((score / 3) * 100) + "%,")
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make this more manageable by constructing a list of questions and answers rather than writing discrete blocks of code for each.

You need to be asking the user if they want to answer questions (or not).

So...

```
Q_and_A = [
    ('What is the capital of Japan', 'Tokyo'),
    ('What is a female Japansese dress called', 'kimono'),
    ('What are Japanese gang members called', 'yakuza')
]

score = 0

for q, a in Q_and_A:
    if input('Would you like to try to answer a question? ').lower() in {'n', 'no'}:
        break
    if input(f'{q}? ').lower() == a.lower():
        print('Correct')
        score += 1
    else:
        print('Incorrect')

print(f'Your total score is {score} out of a possible {len(Q_and_A)}')
```

Thus if you want to add more questions and answers you just change the list of tuples. The rest of the code doesn't need to be changed